# How is the increase in price of commodity related to the quantity of commodity to maintain same selling price

Tags: arithmetic, average, percentages

In what proportion must water be mixed with milk so as to gain 20% by selling mixture at cost price of milk?(water freely available)

The answer is 1:5 and the book says to gain 20% at cost price the milk should be 83.33% of new mixture so the ratio becomes 1:5. Can anyone please explain me how it is 83.33% and not 80%?

Answer (score 0):

The profit margin on a trade is

$$
\frac{\textrm{Sale price}}{\textrm{Cost price}} - 1
$$

and you want this to equal 20%. Say the cost of milk is C, and you are going to mix a proportion F of milk, and (1 - F) of water. Then your sale price will be C (since you are selling it as milk) and your cost price is FC (since the water is free). Therefore you want

$$
\frac{C}{FC} - 1 = 0.2
$$

which rearranges to give

$$
F = \frac{1}{1.2} = 0.8333\dots
$$

Comment: Clearly understood, thank you